# Moving files from multiple directories using Gulp copies the directories as well

Tags: gulp

I'm setting up gulp to move all my html files from different modules into one views folder. Inside modules folder each module folder has the same structure

modulename/client/views/anyFile.html

I've written the gulp task 'move-html'.

```
gulp.task('move-html', function(){
    return gulp.src('./modules/*/client/views/*.html')
    .pipe(htmlmin({ collapseWhitespace: true }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/views'));
});
```

I expected all the html files from all the modules to be copied to ./public/views however, I found the entire module structures copied instead.

Expected: 
index.html

Actual output:
app
 |-client
     |-views
         |-index.html

I'm guessing it's to do with the asterisk after after module/ but can't find any answer of an alternative way.

When I use a file name in gulp.src it works fine e.g. ./modules/app/client/views/*.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that the portion of the path preceding the `*` is important here.  It will form the `base`  of the path.  But that is not what you want.  You want to eliminate parts of the path that include and follow the `*`.  The easiest way to do that is with [gulp-flatten](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-flatten), a package which will remove specified parent directories.

In your case you can simply remove them all like this:

```
.pipe(flatten())
```

leaving only the filenames themselves, which you can then puit into any directories you want.  So:

```
const flatten = require("gulp-flatten");

gulp.task('move-html', function(){
  return gulp.src('./modules/**/client/views/*.html')
    .pipe(htmlmin({ collapseWhitespace: true }))

    .pipe(flatten())

    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/views'));
});
```

Now you will end up with `./public/views/*.html` as you wanted.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply, it was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer as well if you found it helpful and accurate.  Thanks. (click the checkmark)

Comment: Done. Thanks again bud